# Return Partial view from different method in same controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to return a partial view (modal) from another method but I am unsure of how to get the object from the Edit User model into RemoveUserClaim method. When I delete a claim from a user, I want it to return back to the Edit User Modal, right now - I can only get it to redirect to the home maintenance screen.

```c#
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> RemoveUserClaim(UserClaimsViewModel model, string userid, string claimtype)
        {
            var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(model.UserId);

            if (user == null)
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = $"User with Id = {model.UserId} cannot be found";
                return View("~/Views/Administration/Users/UserMaint.cshtml");
            }

            var claims = await userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);

            foreach (var claimtypething in claims)
            {
                if (claimtypething.Type == claimtype)
                {
                    var results = await userManager.RemoveClaimAsync(user, claimtypething);
                    break;
                }
            }


//Right here is where I want to return back to EditUser's modal -----------

            return PartialView("~/Views/Modals/_EditUserModalPartial.cshtml");

        }





   [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> EditUser(string id)
        {
            var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = $"User with Id = {id} cannot be found";
                return View("NotFound");
            }

            var userClaims = await userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
            var userRoles = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

            var model = new EditUserViewModel
            {
                Id = user.Id,
                Email = user.Email,
                UserName = user.UserName,
                City = user.City, 

            };

            //GET LIST OF ROLES (RoleID, RoleName)
            foreach (var RoleName in userRoles)
            {
                //Execute identiy method to get full information for the Role and store into an object (fullroleinfo)
                var fullRoleInfo = await roleManager.FindByNameAsync(RoleName);

                //Store this inforamtion into the Role list in the viewmodel
                var roleinfo = new EditUserViewModel.Role
                {
                    RoleName = fullRoleInfo.Name,
                    RoleID = fullRoleInfo.Id
                };
                model.Roles.Add(roleinfo);
            };

            //GET LIST OF CLAIMS
               foreach (var ClaimName in userClaims)
            {

                var fullClaimInfo = ClaimName;

                var claiminfo = new EditUserViewModel.Claim
                {
                    ClaimType = fullClaimInfo.Type,
                    ClaimID = fullClaimInfo.Value
                };
                ViewBag.ClaimType = fullClaimInfo.Type;
                model.Claims.Add(claiminfo);
            };
            ViewBag.UserModel = model;
            return PartialView("~/Views/Modals/_EditUserModalPartial.cshtml", model);
         }
```

Comment: does removing a claim get triggered from within the edit user modal to begin with? Are you firing the removeUserClaim method via AJAX, or a regular postback? in one part of the method you are potentially returning a whole view, yet later in a different case you want to return a partial. That makes no sense. Returning a full view only makes sense via a full page refresh (postback or clicking a link), whereas returning a partial only makes sense from an AJAX request, where you then add the partial content to the rest of the existing page.

Comment: Without sufficient contextual info it's hard to say, but potentially this remove claim method might be better being called via AJAX, and set it simply to return some JSON saying if it succeeded or failed? Then you simply display the result on screen (or take some other action, if need be) when you receive the response in your JS code. That way there's no need to worry about returning partial views, or model data etc since it'll all still be there in the page. I may have misread the situation, but that's a potential approach you could consider.

Comment: @ADyson, the removeUserClaim is being fired from a button click within the EditUser modal using ASP. I should have removed the other returnView because I just have not edited that line of code right now. I am going to correct it with the answer I get. 

When the RemoveUserClaim succeeds, I want it to return back to the EditUser partial view.

Comment: Ok. So if you just want it to return back to the edit user partial from which it came then follow the suggestion in my second comment